# Using Ampscript to pre-fill form, check box

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, inputcheckboxes

I have a preference center and trying to prefil preference.

Here is my code:

```
 SET @SubscriberKey = "smithandthunder+1320@gmail.comJohn"

  SET @Exposed = Lookup("MasterSubscriberDE","Pref_Exposed","Id", @SubscriberKey)


  IF (LOWERCASE(@Exposed)=="true") THEN 
    SET @ExposedC= "checked" 
    ELSE 
    SET @ExposedC="" 
    ENDIF
```

Here is the code for the check box:

```
<input type="checkbox" 
%%=v(@ExposedC)=%% name="Exposed"  value="true"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span>Exposed
          </span><br/>
```

The page renders fine, but the box is not checked even though I am sure that this subscriber has his preference for exposed to be true.

I will appreciate any pointers on this.

**UPDATE**

I have called my %%=v(@ExposedC)=%% in the body of my email . and taken it out of the text box string. It prints "checked" which shows that the lookup function is working.

When I try to copy this back into the check box string, it throws a 500 error ??!?

I'm not sure if this is a warning sign, but the second "=" in the tag is in red.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in [another post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/202288/input-type-checkbox-attribute-checked-is-not-set-on-load-in-ampscript/202302#202302), there's an alternative way to get this working instead of switching to classic content.

```
%%[IF @industry_news == True THEN]%%
      <input name="industry-news" value="Y" type="checkbox" checked/> 
%%[Else]%%
      <input name="industry-news" value="Y" type="checkbox" /> 
%%[ENDIF]%%
```

Comment: Thanks! This project is so far gone will have to try it next time!

Answer (score 1):

Think this is  an issue with building the landing page with the "new" content builder interface via cloud pages. It seems to be a bug, as I copied and pasted the code into classic editor and it worked just fine.